# Agregar datos a DataGridView sin eliminar los datos anteriores

Tags: vb.net

Estoy haciendo un punto de venta con conexión a SQL Server 2012 pero me surgió un problema. Cuando leo el código de un producto se conecta a la base de datos y se anexa el producto en el `DataGridView` pero cuando leo otro producto se elimina el que ya tenia y se agrega el nuevo
he estado leyendo que hay tablas enlazadas y no enlazadas,`dataset`,`columns`,`rows`,etc

```
Sub consultaproducto(ByVal bb As String, ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
        Try
            adaptador = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from producto where nombre like '" & bb + "%" & "'", cn)
            dt = New DataTable
            adaptador.Fill(dt)
            dgv.DataSource = dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Problemas al conectar con al base de datos ")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Lo que quiero es que al seguir leyendo el código de barras de los productos se sigan agregando productos en el `DataGridView`.

Comment: hola.. por lo que veo estas llenando cada vez que entras a este procedimiento la grilla de vuelta.. no es el resultado que esperas?? Tambien podrias aclarar bien el lenguaje en que trabajas?? visual studio es la herramienta de desarrollo, no un lenguaje (aunque parece que estas en vb.net)

Comment: no al parecer cada vez que realizo esta accion el fill elimina los datos de la tabla y agrega el nuevo dato lo que quiero es que se agrege el nuevo pero que no elimine el que ya tenia

Comment: estas haciendo exactamente lo que describis con tu codigo. El fill rellena con el nuevo datatable.. deberias usar o una grilla desconectada u otro metodo para mostrar los datos..

Comment: si de echo ya he estado buscando pero no he encontrado sabras como realizarlo? soy algo nuevo en .net

Comment: Puedes pasarle una lista de objetos (que parece ser tu mejor opción en este caso). Si mañana nadie te respondió, trato de escribirte una respuesta.

Comment: Concuerdo con @gbianchi que, aparentemente, no entiendes muy bien lo que hace tu código. Simplemente la consulta que haces llena el datatable **dt**, que si vez bien hace una sentencia `dt = new DataTable` y es precisamente en esa linea donde se "borra" el artículo que ya habías consultado y se llena solamente con el último consultado. Tu pregunta a la vez es bastante amplia ya que el código que compartiste tiene varias falencias, pero intenté hacer mi respuesta lo más parecida a tu código para que te funcione y sea tu mérito mejorarlo.

Comment: Lo que quieres es que cuando buscas otro producto lo añada a la tabla y también lo muestre en el DataGridView?

Comment: A nivel de consejo: yo en estos casos lo que hago es añadir la tabla a un DataSet y luego creo una consulta a la que llamo luego (en este caso pondría un FillByNombre). Después de esto, añado primero el Dataset al formulario, luego la tabla y además creo un BindingSource de esa tabla. Para finalizar, con el DataSource del Grid cargo los datos. Para mí es la manera más cómoda de trabajar y es lo que hago siempre.

Answer (score 2):

La solución a tu problema se puede hacer utilizando una **DataTable** declarada en el código fuera del procedimiento **consultaproducto**, y utilizando el código del procedimiento que escribiste (que te funciona y te trae la información) para importar a dicha DataTable la fila obtenida.

```
 Dim dt As DataTable

    Private Sub consultaproducto(ByVal bb As String, ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
        Try

            ' Creo el DataTable que llenaremos con Fill

            Dim DT_ImportoProducto As DataTable
            Dim adaptador = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from producto where nombre like '" & bb + "%" & "'", New MySqlConnection(cMOSTRAR_String))

            ' Llenamos el DataTable donde traemos el producto

            adaptador.Fill(DT_ImportoProducto)

            ' Si el DT posee más de 0 filas
            If DT_ImportoProducto.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                ' Porcion de Código para formatear el DataTable donde 
                ' almacenaremos todos los productos.
                If dt Is Nothing Then
                    ' Copio la estructura (columnas), del resultado obtenido
                    dt = DT_ImportoProducto.Clone
                End If
                ' Importo la Fila obtenida
                dt.ImportRow(DT_ImportoProducto.Rows(0))
            End If
            dgv.DataSource = dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Problemas al conectar con al base de datos ")
        End Try
    End Sub
```